# Iterate through all public methods of a class

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to iterate and print the names of all the functions that I have created in my application while using qt5?

For example lets say that I have created my own class (**myClass**) that contains two public slots

```
int add(int a, int b);
int mul(int a, int b);
```

What I want is later at some point to be able to print that **myClass** contains these two functions by name.

Comment: Define more precisely what you call "all the functions" (which is not the same as "all the public methods")! Please edit your question to improve it! What about templates?

Comment: Quite a philosophical question, actually. What about public methods (say a copy constructor) which could be generated if needed, but are not explicitly defined?

Comment: Then those public methods won't ever find themselves inside that list I would suppose, yet I wouldn't call this a philosophical question since getting at least the predefined methods could be useful to some. We could try moving this to the Sceptics forum though and see what they say :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [QMetaObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html) for this, if you do some preparation. With `​methodCount()` you find the number of published methods, with `method(int idx)` you can access the `QMetaMethod` objects.

The requirements are:

1. The class must be a subclass of `QObject`
2. You must use the `Q_OBJECT` macro in the class body
3. The class must be compiled through `moc`
4. Methods that are not a SLOT or SIGNAL must be declared using `Q_INVOKABLE`

**Update:**
For your example you can use this:

```
class MyClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
   int add(int a, int b);
   int mul(int a, int b);
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE int notaslot();
};

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    MyClass obj;
    QMetaObject *mobj = obj.metaObject();
    for (int i = 0; i < mobj->methodCount(); ++i) {
       QMetaMethod method = mobj->method(i);
       if (method.access() == QMetaMethod::Public) {
          std::cout << method.name().toStdString();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just now sow your code example, could it be possible that *method.signature()* should be *method.methodSignature();*

Comment: You are right. I used Qt 4.8 documentation on that part, where it is `const char *signature() const`. In Qt 5 its `QByteArray methodSignature() const`. But for only getting the name, there is now `QByteArray name() const`. I updated the example

Answer (score 0):

It is not *easily* possible., but with some effort it might be doable.

You could customize some existing C++ compiler to do that. For example, you might customize your recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (`g++` version 4.8 or 4.9) using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), but that probably would take you a week or two of  work at least.

You could also run `nm -C` on the debug version (or at least a non-stripped version) of your executable. That would show you all the C++ symbols.

If you care only about Qt *slots* the `moc` is extracting these.

<sup>PS. Your question is unclear. Define *exactly* what names you want to show.</sup>